# How to request rest api after getting access token. php & curl

Tags: rest-api, php, oauth, curl

I am able to authenticate with salesforce and receive a token using php & curl, below. However my next step is to use the token id to query salesforce (e.g objects) and i am not getting anything back. I am new to salesforce, php and rest api's.  I have tried several ways, the code below is the last change i made and i get http 400 error. 
When i run curl on my terminal (MacOS) with the access token, i get back the json i expect.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$cookie_file = tempnam('./temp', 'cookie');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=VRi0wrACym0LPy2siVyKXzCLUzC7mz8TLtMapjl&client_secret=2800232856&username=kathy&password=nottoselfzvrGTNeFWTg7WEWfC1MP&format=json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json   = json_decode($result);
$atoken = $json->access_token;
echo $atoken;

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization', 'OAuth '+$atoken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);

$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($curl_response);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$atoken` actually has a token? Can you `var_dump()` it?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- You need to use `instance_url` in the second call
- String concatenation in PHP uses '.', not '+'
- As Lex mentioned, the cookie jar is not needed with OAuth or the REST API

So your code for the second call should look like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json->instance_url . "/services/data/v26.0/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization', 'OAuth ' . $atoken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

And I hope that isn't your real client secret. If it is, go reset it, right now!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure `$atoken` has a value, the following code should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization', 'OAuth '.$atoken));
```

So, remove the header from the url option and set it separately in the header option.

Comment: i am not getting the 400 error anymore but now am getting [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]. I've modified above code to include suggested changes.

Comment: Can you try it without the cookie jar? Maybe the session id of a previous session is loaded from the cookie. Have you double-checked the credentials you use to get the session token?